# Want to write a query returns as object in Doctrine

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

Just write a query like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('r.title, r.title_safe, r.description')
->from('Regions r')
->where('pr.page_id = ?', 1)
->leftJoin('r.Page_regions pr');

$results = $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

but i want to $results as object. How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Just use execute method without arguments.

$q->execute();

Comment: that's not giving the same result as array. Just want to return fields back.

Comment: What do you mean `just want to return fields back`?

Comment: want to same results as execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

like: 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => Header
            [title_safe] => header
            [description] => Sayfa üst barı.
        )

but i dont want get results like array i want to get results like object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('r.title, r.title_safe, r.description')
->from('Regions r')
->where('pr.page_id = ?', 1)
->leftJoin('r.Page_regions pr');

$q = $q->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getResult() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `HYDRATE_ARRAY` flag, which returns all of the results as arrays. You can omit this flag to have the results returned as objects.

Because `Doctrine_Query::execute()` returns a Doctrine_Collection object, you can call a number of methods to get the results that you want (see the [Doctrine_Collection API Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_collection.html)). If you just want a single result, try something like this:

```php
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('r.title, r.title_safe, r.description')
    ->from('Regions r')
    ->where('pr.page_id = ?', 1)
    ->leftJoin('r.Page_regions pr');

    /* @var Doctrine_Record */
    $results = $q->execute()->getFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought there was a way to obtain the `PDOStatement` representation. Let me get back to you about that.

Here's a quick solution in the meantime. But this will only work with data from actual model (data of relations will be arrays of the object).

```
$objs = array();
foreach ($q->fetchArray() as $arr) {
    $objs = (object)$arr;
}
```

**- Edit -**

Could not find it. But you could just extend the `Doctrine_Query` class.

```
class App_Doctrine_Query extends Doctrine_Query
{
    public function fetchObjects(array $params = array())
    {
        return array_map(array($this, 'convertArrayToObject'), $this->fetchArray($params));
    }


    private function convertArrayToObject(array $arr)
    {
        $obj = new stdClass();

        foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) {
                $val = $this->convertArrayToObject($val);
            }

            $obj->$key = $val;
        }

        return $obj;
    }
}
```

And in your bootstrapper you would add something like this:

```
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CLASS, 'App_Doctrine_Query');
```